# Not able to use Sessions in ASP MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session

I start the page from a landing page where I call a function from a Controller, to assign values to some sessions. But I seem to not be able to use them, as I get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception on the first line of the body of the following function:

```
public void assignNewUserToSession(string currentButtonID, string user, string app)
        {
            Session["buttonID"] = currentButtonID;
            Session["userID"] = user;
            Session["appID"] = app;
        }
```

This exception is usually thrown when one is using a variable that has not been initialized, that is = to null or nothing. But as far as I know, Sessions don't have to be initialized in any other way than I have done it in the code above.

Here is where I call the upper function:

```
public void landingPage()
        {
            FC.assignNewUserToSession("34", "asd", "gsds");

            Media(); // This is the view Controller for another page.
        }
```

What might be the problem ?

Comment: Where is `landingPage` called?

Comment: @RGraham - I set it to be called on run of the solution. As `Start URL`.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal - the object reference of the other controller, where the function `assignNewUserToSession()` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

instead of

```
Session
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   HttpContext.Current.Session["buttonID"]=currentButtonID;
   HttpContext.Current.Session["userID"] = user;
   HttpContext.Current.Session["appID"] = app;
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. But I couldn't use it just like that. I had to use the full library reference `System.Web.HttpContext....` otherwise it wouldn't find "Current" as property. But I couldn't find to include the library as `using System.Web.HttpContext;`. Do you know why is that ?

Comment: include System.Web in namespace

Comment: I have it. I am not that noob. :D